# memset on static array

Tags: c++, arrays, memset

I am a little confused about what to pass as the first parameter to memset when you have to set the elements of a static array. I've been searching but I couldn't find the answers to some specific questions I have.

If I have an array declared as:

```
char arr[10];
```

I have seen that these two calls are valid and produce the same effect:

```
memset( arr, 0, 10);
memset( &arr, 0, 10);
```

My specific questions are:

1- Why do they have the same effect on arr?

2- What is the different between these calls?

3- Which one would be considered the correct one?

Thank you!

Comment: Correct way to set them all to zero: `char arr[10] = {};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storage duration has nothing to do with it; an array is an array.  This expression:

```
&arr
```

produces a `char (*)[10]`, i.e., a pointer to an array of `char` with 10 elements.  However, when `arr` is passed to a function like so:

```
memset(arr, 0, 10);
```

it degrades to a pointer to the first element, i.e., a `char*`.  These are not the same thing.  The "correct" (idiomatic) call is:

```
memset(arr, 0, 10);
```

However, in this case they are both converted to a `void*` when passed to `memset` and interpreted in the function as an `unsigned char*`.  Since they both point to the same place it produces the same result.

However, it is important to realize that, when dealing with the true respective types (i.e., not a `void*`), a pointer to an array is *not* the same as a pointer to the first element of an array.

For example, incrementing a `char (*)[10]` will increment the pointer `sizeof(char[10])` bytes, while incrementing a `char*` will increment only one byte.

Comment: One correction: `and interpreted in the function as a char*` should be changed to `unsigned char*`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do they have the same effect on arr? What is the different between these calls?

Because the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element (arrays decay into pointers to their first element when passed to a function), it's just that they have a different type. `arr` has type `char[10]`, that decays into `char *` when passed to a function. In contrast, `&arr` has the type `char (*)[10]` which doesn't change when passed as a function argument.

> Which one would be considered the correct one?

As long as the function doesn't expect a specific type, i. e. it accepts `void *`, either one is good. If the called function, however, expects that either of the types be specified, then the other one should not be used, since then your program would be malformed and invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `memset( arr, 0, 10);`? It remains valid if declaration of the array is changed to `char *arr = new char[10]` for some reason.

Comment: @user502144 We're not talking about the "when it changes" case. Or, more precisely, I have mentioned in the last part when the two are valid.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Why do they have the same effect on arr?

They both contain the same value which is the address of the beginning of the array.

> 2- What is the different between these calls?

`arr` decays to a pointer to char, i.e. `char*` (this conversion happens when you pass the name of an array to a function) and `&arr` is a pointer to an **array** of char, i.e. `char (*)[]`.

> 3- Which one would be considered the correct one?

I would use `arr`. `memset` accepts a `void*` which is the reason both work.

Also, note that `char arr[10] = {};` can be used to zero initialize the array.

Comment: Careful - `arr` is **not** a pointer to a char, but it can decay to one.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Thanks, it's hard to be precise when you are typing fast (changed wording).